# html textbox in ie 7 and 8 not checking on image click

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I can not seem to get this checkbox to work in ie8, i do have JS working with the form, however i do not believe that it is the JS causing the problem. I have not checked to see if this works in ie7, but it does work in all other major browsers. Anyone have an idea as to why it doesnt work? ill provide code as well as a live example.

live:
http://jsbin.com/uburan/3/edit

markup:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function func()
{
var img1= document.getElementById("img1");

if(document.getElementById('interest1').checked)
{
    img1.src = "images/" + "internetbutton.gif";
    img1.name = "off";
}
else
{
    img1.src = "images/" + "internetbuttonchecked.gif";
    img1.name = "on";
}
}
</script>



</head>

<body>
<form>
<p align="center">
<input type="checkbox" name="interest1" id="interest1" value="x">
<input type="checkbox" name="interest2" id="interest2" value="x">
<input type="checkbox" name="interest3" id="interest3" value="x"></p>   
<p align="center">
<label for="interest1" id="label-interest1"><img src="images/img1.jpg" width="781" height="800" onclick="func()" id="img1" /></label>
<label for="interest2" id="label-interest2"><img src="/images/img2.jpg" width="781" height="800" /></label>
<label for="interest3" id="label-interest3"><img src="/images/img3.jpg" width="781" height="800" /></label></P><!-- code making checkbox be an image-->
</form>
```

Comment: I believe it is because you have the `img` nested inside the label. IE probably ignores the `for` attribute in this case.

Comment: @Shmiddty do you happen to know a way i can work around this?

Comment: Well, it seems to me that you're over-complicating something. What is it that you're trying to accomplish? Why do you need to use a checkbox at all?

Comment: @Shmiddty the checkbox is being used to send variables to a form, the user can select one of three items, or two, or all of them, if they desire

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread's a year old, but I found the solution for this.

The problem is that the image inside the `label` catches your click event, and it's not passed on to the label. Every other Element inside the `label` will forward the event, but an image won't, at least not in IE.

So, the only thing to do is prevent the image from getting click events using `pointer-events: none;`.

Imagine your form like this *(NOTE: The behaviour doesn't occur when input elements are used outside of `form`tags!)*:

```
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" name="interest1" id="interest1" value="1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="interest2" id="interest2" value="2">

    <label for="interest1" id="label-interest1"><img src="some/image1.jpg"/></label>
    <label for="interest2" id="label-interest2"><img src="some/image2.jpg"/></label>
</form>
```

Your CSS would be:

```
label {
    border:1px solid red;
    display:inline-block;
}
label > img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;

    pointer-events: none;
}
```

A live example can be found here:
http://jsbin.com/OxOlETU/2/edit

Feel free and try removing the line saying `pointer-events: none;` for testing purposes.

**Edit (2014/01/16):** After a bit of testing, this seems to affect only the IE versions 7, 8, and *11*. In IE 9/10, nesting an image inside a `label` works like a charm.